# Phonegap: App thinks my phones screen is smaller than the app, resulting in scrolling (android)

Tags: android, cordova, zooming, muse

So I first had created an app with HTML/CSS/JS self-typed and after that, I've created a new version with Adobe Muse. Both uploaded to Phonegap, turned into APK and uploaded->Installed on my phone (HTC One X, resolution: 1280x720)

The whole site (both versions) are based on a 1280x720 screen and all sizes are based on that. However, on both versions; if I load it on my phone, it results in a very much zoomed version, which makes you be able to 'scroll' on the app. Somehow.. I can't seem to fix that.

My question: How do I fix it, so my screen size is the same as the apps' (html files)? Resulting in no scrolling? (And for bigger/smaller screens automaticly up/downscaling?).

Comment: did u notice that you don't have all the screen ? there is a status bar in the header of the screen ;)

Comment: I've set the configuration to fullscreen. So I don't have a status bar at the top.